# Angular form saves data from only last input and the rest are empty

Tags: angular, forms, input

When I click add new Item and have multiple inputs in console after submit there's only data from last input. Every other is empty like : name ''. I dont know what to change to make it works even chat gpt doesnt help. I think there's something wrong with my loop for multi inputs.

Here's my HTML code :

```
 <form method="POST" [formGroup]="addInvoiceForm" (ngSubmit)="addData()">
  <div class="formularz" *ngFor="let item of items">
    <mat-form-field >
      <mat-label>Name</mat-label>
      <input type="text" matInput formControlName="name"   maxlength="30" minlength="3"required>
      <mat-error *ngIf="addInvoiceF['name'].errors && addInvoiceF['name'].errors['required']">Name is required</mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field>
      <mat-label>Count</mat-label>
      <input type="number"  formControlName="count" matInput  maxlength="100" minlength="1">
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field >
      <mat-label>Price</mat-label>
      <input type="number" matInput formControlName="price"  maxlength="1000000" minlength="1" required>
      <mat-error *ngIf="addInvoiceF['price'].errors && addInvoiceF['price'].errors['required']">Price is required</mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
    <button mat-icon-button color="primary" class="delete" matTooltip="Remove item" (click)="deleteForm(item)">
      <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="add-new">
    <button type="button" mat-icon-button color="primary" class="add" matTooltip="Add new item" (click)="addForm()">
      <mat-icon>add</mat-icon>
      Add new item
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="add">
    <button mat-icon-button color="primary" class="myButton" id="add_data_button">
      Submit
    </button>
  </div>
</form>
```

and my Typescript:

```
   `import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { FormControl, FormGroupDirective, NgForm, Validators, FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
    import { ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
    import { PagesService } from '../pages.service';
    import { Router } from '@angular/router';
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-new-invoice',
      templateUrl: './new-invoice.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./new-invoice.component.css']
    })
    export class NewInvoiceComponent implements OnInit {
    
      addInvoiceForm!: FormGroup;
      get addInvoiceF() { return this.addInvoiceForm.controls; }
    
      items: any[] = [
        { form: new FormGroup({
            name: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
            count: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
            price: new FormControl('', Validators.required)
          })
        }
      ];
    
      formRows: any[] = [{ name: '', count: 1, price: '' }];
    
      constructor(
        private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
        private pagesService: PagesService,
        private router: Router
      ) {
        window.addEventListener('beforeunload', () => {
          for (let key in localStorage) {
            if (key.includes('formRows')) {
              localStorage.removeItem(key);
            }
          }
        });
      }
    
    
      ngOnInit(): void {
        this.addInvoiceForm = this.formBuilder.group({
          name: ['', Validators.required],
          count: ['', ],
          price: ['', Validators.required],
        });
      }
    
      addFormRow() {
        this.formRows.push({ name: '', count: 1, price: '' });
      }
    
      addForm() {
        const newForm = {
          form: new FormGroup({
            name: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
            count: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
            price: new FormControl('', Validators.required)
          })
        };
        this.items.push(newForm);
      }
    
      deleteForm(item: any) {
        const index = this.items.indexOf(item);
        if (index !== -1) {
          this.items.splice(index, 1);
        }
      }
    
      addData() {
  if (this.addInvoiceForm.invalid) {
    return;
  }

  const formRows = this.items.map(item => ({
    name: item.form.value.name || '',
    count: item.form.value.count || '',
    price: item.form.value.price || '' 
  }));
  
  formRows.push({
    name: this.addInvoiceForm.value.name || '',
    count: this.addInvoiceForm.value.count || '',
    price: this.addInvoiceForm.value.price || '' 
  });
  
  this.pagesService.setFormData(formRows);
  
  console.log(formRows);
  
  this.router.navigate(['/preview-invoice']);
}
    }
```

`